# How to automate report publishing in Power BI

Tags: python, powershell, powerbi

I have a report that suffer constant changes and need to be re-published frequently.

I want to do an script or a Power Automate flow to update it automatically.

I already tried [Power BI Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps), it have the publish function, but it do not publish to an existing report, it create a new every time. Neither Power Automate have it, at least at first look.

I know how to update a dataset automatically, but that is not what I need. I really need to do an equivalent of opening Power BI and click on the *Publish* button.

Comment: Not gonna lie but easiest way is using UiPath based automation. As we are doing something similar and coding everything is a quite a hassle.

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi That exactly what I had to do, unfortunately.

Comment: I found this script: https://github.com/DarknessTech/pbixrefresher2020/blob/master/pbixrefresher.py and made some changes, because it's from 2020 and it's obsolete. My script: https://github.com/lucasrantunes/pbixrefresher/blob/master/pbixrefresher.py